# Problems installing python 3.6 with pyenv on Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: python

When installing Python 3.6.13 on my MacBook Air, OS Big Sur, using the command pyenv install 3.6.13 I get this error:

```
Installing Python-3.6.13...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 11.3 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/7j/0qtpb8vs1_s34ynv0f6rrs840000gn/T/python-build.20210304114832.65954
Results logged to /var/folders/7j/0qtpb8vs1_s34ynv0f6rrs840000gn/T/python-build.20210304114832.65954.log

Last 10 log lines:
./Modules/posixmodule.c:8210:15: error: implicit declaration of function 'sendfile' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        ret = sendfile(in, out, offset, &sbytes, &sf, flags);
              ^
./Modules/posixmodule.c:10432:5: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
    Py_FatalError("abort() called from Python code didn't abort!");
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
1 warning generated.
make: *** [Modules/posixmodule.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this or another work around to install python 3.6.13 would be greatly appreciated. I currently have python 3.8, but need 3.6 in order to run:

```
conda install -c deezer-research spleeter
```

Comment: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1740 seems to be the same as your 3.6 issue

Comment: Have you looked at `asdf`? https://asdf-vm.com/
It's personal preference, but I found it the easiest way to juggle the python versioning headaches.

Comment: @Everett `asdf` is awesome but it uses `pyenv` under the hood, so this thread is actual for both of the tools.

Comment: Seems like this is an issue Apples new Clang release. Here is the fix.
https://issueantenna.com/repo/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2284

Comment: For macOS 13.4 Ventura, I hit a similar issue. A complete uninstall and reinstall of Homebrew and its formulae worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76847742/2214933

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Thanks to jordanm,
The solution was to follow https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1740#issuecomment-738749988

```
brew reinstall zlib bzip2
```

From people's comments (thanks to Lukasz Czerwinski and Alex Veksler) it seems many view this next step as optional (and even dangerous) and prefer to skip it; though, it's worth a try if nothing else is working:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
```

Whether you chose to skip the last step or not, continue by editing `.zshrc` or `.bashrc` using:

```
nano ~/.zshrc or nano ~/.bashrc
```

and add:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib -L/usr/local/opt/bzip2/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include -I/usr/local/opt/bzip2/include"
```

after editing and saving that file, run:

```
. ~/.zshrc or . ~/.bashrc
```

Then run the command below to install (changing 3.6.0 for the desired patch)

```
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include -I$(brew --prefix bzip2)/include -I$(brew --prefix readline)/include -I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib -L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib -L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib -L$(brew --prefix bzip2)/lib" pyenv install --patch 3.6.0 < <(curl -sSL https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/8ea6353.patch\?full_index\=1)
```

Comment: I confirm it worked for Python 3.6.13 for pyenv 1.2.26 on MacOS Big Sur (11.2.3). (Actually, I skipped `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` and `xcode-select --install` but followed all the rest)

Comment: This is not working for Mac M1 with Big Sur 11.2.2.

Comment: Worked for python 3.5.10 MacOs 11.2

Comment: It worked for me, python 3.8.0 - MacOs 11.2.1

Comment: This worked for me, 2019 Macbook Pro Intel MacOS 11.4, Python 3.6.9.

Comment: @m-ketan Python 3.9 is the first version of Python to have full support for Mac M1.

Comment: @BoarGules Yes i figured that and ended up using 3.9.5.

Comment: Worked for Python 3.6.8 on macOS 11.4.  Don't forget to run the last command from OP.

Comment: It worked for me! Thanks! Big Sur 11.5.2, Python 3.7.2

Comment: I have been on Intel Macs for about four years ago, and I generally get an error like this after an OS update.  Almost every time: `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools && xcode-select --install` fixes the issue.  It is as the CommandLineTools don't get updated correctly.

Comment: I was able to install Python 3.6 on Big Sur 11.6.1. However when I try to run python using the command : /Users/myuserid/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/bin/python3.6, I get a message - "xcode-select: Failed to locate 'python3.6', requesting installation of command line developer tools". I have installed xcode command line tool multiple times, but get same error. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Running the command that starts with CFLAGS as shown, I got a 
`ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?` error. 
I believe this is because the `brew --prefix openssl` command was outputting OpenSSL@3 in 2022, and by changing the command to include `brew --prefix openssl@1.1` instead in the two places it occurs, I was able to get 3.6.9 to install.

Comment: After I added `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`to mi `~/.zshrc` my brew started to point `/usr/local/` instead of `/opt/homebrew/` on `which brew`. Be aware of that.

Answer (score 25):

According to this: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1737#issuecomment-731672292 this is related to a commit issue and the following fixes it. It worked for me.

```
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include -I$(brew --prefix bzip2)/include -I$(brew --prefix readline)/include -I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include" 

LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib -L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib -L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib -L$(brew --prefix bzip2)/lib"

pyenv install --patch 3.6.13 < <(curl -sSL https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/8ea6353.patch\?full_index\=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for distilling this -- to others: this is the right answer

Comment: Also if you are on apple silicon (M1), prefix install comand with `arch -x86_64`, otherwise it fails with `configure: error: Unexpected output of 'arch' on OSX`

Comment: This worked for me with python 3.6.14 on bigsur 11.6. 

Many thanks

Comment: This did finally work for me on intel mac with 12.0.1 Monterey.

Comment: This fixed installing Python 3.7.2 on macOS 11.5.2 (Big Sur).

Comment: This also works for Python 3.5.10 on macOS 11.6 (same patch). I don't see the need to add stuff to .bashrc.

Answer (score 8):

The following steps finally worked for my **MacBook Air M1** with **Big Sur 11.6**.

‼️ Please note that this instruction is for Rosetta 2 emulated x86 terminal.

1. Install brew:

   ```
   arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
   ```
2. Install the recommended dependencies:

   ```
   arch -x86_64 brew install openssl readline sqlite3 xz zlib
   ```
3. Install Pyenv with brew:

   ```
   arch -x86_64 brew install pyenv
   ```
4. Configure your shell's environment (in my case zsh):

   ```
   echo 'eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> ~/.zshrc
   ```
5. Restart the terminal.
6. Add environment variables (in my case the problem was with zlib and openssl):

   ```
   export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib"
   export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include"
   export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib"
   export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include"
   ```
7. Install the required Python version with patch:

   ```
   arch -x86_64 pyenv install --patch 3.6.15 <<(curl -sSL https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/8ea6353.patch\?full_index\=1)
   ```
8. Switch shell to new Python version:

   ```
   pyenv shell 3.6.15
   ```
9. Check the currently used Python version:

   ```
   pyenv which python3
   ```

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Jacob Anderson was right, but it’s worth noting that there's no need to perform the dangerous step:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Things worked for me (installed Python 3.6.0 on MacOS 11.4) without doing it. Thanks to Jacob!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this on mu ubuntu machine, I uninstalled Brew and reinstalled pyenv from source. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include -I$(brew --prefix bzip2)/include -I$(brew --prefix readline)/include -I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib -L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib -L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib -L$(brew --prefix bzip2)/lib" pyenv install --patch 3.6.13 < <(curl -sSL https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/8ea6353.patch\?full_index\=1)
```

it Worked on MacOs 11.2.2