# Can't build any Python version on Mac OS X 13.4 with pyenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyenv

I recently install the latest Mac OSX upgrade (currently running 13.4) and I can't build Python with pyenv anymore (I suspect it's related although not 100% sure).

`pyenv` was installed through `brew install` (I'm using `2.3.19`), and was able to build Python 3.10.4 just fine. I wanted to reinstall the same Python version I was using (3.10.4) and got this error message:

```
BUILD FAILED (OS X 13.4 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/5j/xmpgv80d18s_r90jvtyftpph0000gn/T/python-build.20230611185357.74229
Results logged to /var/folders/5j/xmpgv80d18s_r90jvtyftpph0000gn/T/python-build.20230611185357.74229.log

Last 10 log lines:
  File "/private/var/folders/5j/xmpgv80d18s_r90jvtyftpph0000gn/T/python-build.20230611185357.74229/Python-3.10.12/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 287, in _main
    return _bootstrap(
  File "/private/var/folders/5j/xmpgv80d18s_r90jvtyftpph0000gn/T/python-build.20230611185357.74229/Python-3.10.12/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 203, in _bootstrap
    return _run_pip([*args, *_PACKAGE_NAMES], additional_paths)
  File "/private/var/folders/5j/xmpgv80d18s_r90jvtyftpph0000gn/T/python-build.20230611185357.74229/Python-3.10.12/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 104, in _run_pip
    return subprocess.run(cmd, check=True).returncode
  File "/private/var/folders/5j/xmpgv80d18s_r90jvtyftpph0000gn/T/python-build.20230611185357.74229/Python-3.10.12/Lib/subprocess.py", line 526, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/private/var/folders/5j/xmpgv80d18s_r90jvtyftpph0000gn/T/python-build.20230611185357.74229/Python-3.10.12/python.exe', '-W', 'ignore::DeprecationWarning', '-c', '\nimport runpy\nimport sys\nsys.path = [\'/var/folders/5j/xmpgv80d18s_r90jvtyftpph0000gn/T/tmp18yfiiwu/setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl\', \'/var/folders/5j/xmpgv80d18s_r90jvtyftpph0000gn/T/tmp18yfiiwu/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl\'] + sys.path\nsys.argv[1:] = [\'install\', \'--no-cache-dir\', \'--no-index\', \'--find-links\', \'/var/folders/5j/xmpgv80d18s_r90jvtyftpph0000gn/T/tmp18yfiiwu\', \'--root\', \'/\', \'--upgrade\', \'setuptools\', \'pip\']\nrunpy.run_module("pip", run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)\n']' died with <Signals.SIGABRT: 6>.
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

(I don't really get why it tries to do anything with a `.exe` file...)

Since then, I tried almost lead I could find, including reinstalling pyenv, reinstalling xcode-select, updating homebrew and upgrading all packages. Nothing helped.

I've tried installing 3.9, 3.10 and 3.11 (latest with each). On 3.9 and 3.10 I get the same error with the exe file. When I try 3.11 I get something else:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_libintl_bindtextdomain", referenced from:
      __locale_bindtextdomain in _localemodule.o
  "_libintl_dcgettext", referenced from:
      __locale_dcgettext in _localemodule.o
  "_libintl_dgettext", referenced from:
      __locale_dgettext in _localemodule.o
  "_libintl_gettext", referenced from:
      __locale_gettext in _localemodule.o
  "_libintl_setlocale", referenced from:
      __locale_setlocale in _localemodule.o
      __locale_localeconv in _localemodule.o
  "_libintl_textdomain", referenced from:
      __locale_textdomain in _localemodule.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-16: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Programs/_freeze_module] Error 1

BUILD FAILED (OS X 13.4 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/5j/xmpgv80d18s_r90jvtyftpph0000gn/T/python-build.20230611184550.63292
Results logged to /var/folders/5j/xmpgv80d18s_r90jvtyftpph0000gn/T/python-build.20230611184550.63292.log

Last 10 log lines:
  "_libintl_gettext", referenced from:
      __locale_gettext in _localemodule.o
  "_libintl_setlocale", referenced from:
      __locale_setlocale in _localemodule.o
      __locale_localeconv in _localemodule.o
  "_libintl_textdomain", referenced from:
      __locale_textdomain in _localemodule.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-16: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Programs/_freeze_module] Error 1
```

Does anyone have any lead? I feel like every time I'm upgrading my Mac OS, I completely break my whole dev environment...

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue myself, and found a solution on the pyenv issue tracker, [Installing python on MacBook Pro M2 - ensurepip "died with <Signals.SIGABRT: 6>."](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2707#issuecomment-1597030394).

1. Get all my installed formulae with `brew list`, and save the list for their reinstallation.
2. [Uninstall Homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#how-do-i-uninstall-homebrew).
3. Satisfy [requirements to reinstall Homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation#macos-requirements).
4. [Reinstall Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) with `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`.
5. Reinstall your formulae with `brew install [space-separated list of formulae]`. This probably includes `pyenv`, but if not, add it to your list to install. Note, if you migrated from an old macOS, then some brew formulae might be deprecated or not installable, such as `postgresql@9.6`. You will need to remove and omit these items from your list and attempt to install the remaining list items.
6. Reconfigure formulae. For example, Apache's configuration moved from `/usr/local/etc/httpd/` to `/opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/`.

Finally the suggestion to first try reinstalling all the formulae did not work for me. I had to take this sledgehammer approach to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem after I updated macOS to Sonoma 14.4

I was able to fix it thru reinstalling mac ports.
[This is the official instruction.](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration)