# Problem installing Python 3.6.5 on macOS 12.6 Monterey with Intel chip

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyenv

I get the following error when I use `pyenv` to install python version 3.6.5 using the command `pyenv install 3.6.5`:

**Error** -
`configure: error: internal configure error for the platform triplet, please file a bug report`

I've also tried the suggestion in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66482346/problems-installing-python-3-6-with-pyenv-on-mac-os-big-sur), however I ran into the same issue.

**Command** - `LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib -L$(brew --prefix bzip2)/lib" pyenv install --patch 3.6.5 < <(curl -sSL https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/8ea6353.patch\?full_index\=1)`

**Detailed Logs** -

```
Downloading openssl-1.0.2k.tar.gz...
-> https://pyenv.github.io/pythons/6b3977c61f2aedf0f96367dcfb5c6e578cf37e7b8d913b4ecb6643c3cb88d8c0
Installing openssl-1.0.2k...
Installed openssl-1.0.2k to /Users/weaver/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5

python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.6.5.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/Python-3.6.5.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.6.5...
patching file Misc/NEWS.d/next/macOS/2020-06-24-13-51-57.bpo-41100.mcHdc5.rst
patching file configure
Hunk #1 succeeded at 3369 (offset -57 lines).
patching file configure.ac
Hunk #1 succeeded at 495 (offset -15 lines).
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.6 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/vp/qpmxg0vx6dx396bx974srp380000gn/T/python-build.20220928220948.83599
Results logged to /var/folders/vp/qpmxg0vx6dx396bx974srp380000gn/T/python-build.20220928220948.83599.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for --with-cxx-main=<compiler>... no
checking for clang++... no
configure:

  By default, distutils will build C++ extension modules with "clang++".
  If this is not intended, then set CXX on the configure command line.

checking for the platform triplet based on compiler characteristics... darwin
configure: error: internal configure error for the platform triplet, please file a bug report
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

After researching the question I could not install python 3.6, the solution I found was that only a few versions could be installed, which is described here https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2112, version 3.7.13 was installed without problems

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).