# Unique error in pyenv installation of python 3.10 on macOS 12.6 Monterey (M1 Pro chip)

Tags: python, xcode, homebrew, pyenv, darwin

I am trying to install python using pyenv but am running into the following error after having already followed the instructions in the top response in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66482346/problems-installing-python-3-6-with-pyenv-on-mac-os-big-sur):

```
Arashk@Arashks-MBP ~ % pyenv install 3.10.7
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.10.7.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.7/Python-3.10.7.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.10.7...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.6 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/nm/zb8gvgds6nx448zw248vlg1c0000gn/T/python-build.20221025053833.56249
Results logged to /var/folders/nm/zb8gvgds6nx448zw248vlg1c0000gn/T/python-build.20221025053833.56249.log

Last 10 log lines:
  File "/private/var/folders/nm/zb8gvgds6nx448zw248vlg1c0000gn/T/python-build.20221025053833.56249/Python-3.10.7/Lib/importlib/_common.py", line 52, in get_resource_reader
    return reader(spec.name)  # type: ignore
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 548, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1081, in get_resource_reader
  File "/private/var/folders/nm/zb8gvgds6nx448zw248vlg1c0000gn/T/python-build.20221025053833.56249/Python-3.10.7/Lib/importlib/readers.py", line 2, in <module>
    import zipfile
  File "/private/var/folders/nm/zb8gvgds6nx448zw248vlg1c0000gn/T/python-build.20221025053833.56249/Python-3.10.7/Lib/zipfile.py", line 6, in <module>
    import binascii
ImportError: dlopen(/private/var/folders/nm/zb8gvgds6nx448zw248vlg1c0000gn/T/python-build.20221025053833.56249/Python-3.10.7/build/lib.macosx-12.6-arm64-3.10/binascii.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace (_crc32)
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Any ideas?