# Not able to install different python version using pyenv on venturaOS

Tags: python, pyenv, macos-ventura

MACPRO140 ~ % pyenv install 3.8.3
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.8.3.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.3/Python-3.8.3.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.8.3...
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 13.2.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/nb/98mm83kx2qqdwz182xv9v_b40000gn/T/python-build.20230309225809.6169
Results logged to /var/folders/nb/98mm83kx2qqdwz182xv9v_b40000gn/T/python-build.20230309225809.6169.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for --with-cxx-main=... no
checking for clang++... no
configure:

By default, distutils will build C++ extension modules with "clang++".
If this is not intended, then set CXX on the configure command line.

checking for the platform triplet based on compiler characteristics... darwin
configure: error: internal configure error for the platform triplet, please file a bug report
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

I want to install and use different versions of python on my mac ventura os

Comment: i found the answer in another post. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66482346/problems-installing-python-3-6-with-pyenv-on-mac-os-big-sur)